# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. I don't think I have much of a choice here, do I?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
IgnorePointer(
              child: cProtractor & darkModeOn
                  ? Positioned.fill(
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Center(
                            child:
                                Image.asset('lib/assets/img/cprot2white.png',
                                    width: 500.0, height: 500.0),
                          )))
                  : SizedBox())
        ]));
  }
}
```

The above function switches on and off a protractor overlay for my Google Map. Its parent is a         body: Stack(children: [. Is there any way to fix this or get rid of the error? The function is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove Ignore pointer as parent widget of Positioned Widget as **Positioned widgets are placed directly inside Stack widgets.**

You can achieve the same using below code

```
  Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset('lib/assets/img/cprot2white.png',
                        width: 500.0, height: 500.0),
                  ),
                ))),
```

Here just the hierarchy of the widgets are changed

Comment: Now there doesn't seem to be a way to have cProtractor & !darkModeOn & !satModeOn included. :/

Comment: nevermind. I threw it on top and it works! Thank you!